# Using mysql code in a javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm stumped I've looked all over the internet and found no real way to access mysql within javascript, therefore I can't do what I need to.

Basically my javascript code is loading random websites using Iframes and I would like those list of sites to be pulled from a mysql database, but I see no way in doing this. I've tried using php's include function in javascript with no luck.

Any ideas?

**More information:**

Im using a script I have on my server called sitelist.js for the source of the script. All that script contains is the following:

```
targetURLs = [
'http://www.aol.com',
'http://www.yahoo.com',
'http://www.bing.com'
];
```

But i would like it to load websites from the mysql database instead of having those websites.

Comment: First off, javascript should not have direct access to your database.  Second, what do you mean bt "I've tried using php's include function in javascript"?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the role of javascript. Mysql runs on the server, and so must be accessed by another language on the server. Javascript runs on the client's machine, and therefore cannot access mysql directly. Look into AJAX, which lets javascript call your PHP files (and more).

Comment: Why don't you just make a PHP script that returns a JSON list of those website strings. Then you can do whatever you want with the list in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something along these lines, with `$sites` being your array of urls from the database...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sites = JSON.parse("<?php echo addslashes(json_encode($sites)); ?>");
    // now do stuff with sites.
</script>
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused on the implementation of this code. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: First you use PHP to get your list of URLs from MySQL and put them in an array. Then use the code I gave you to transfer them into JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense. :D

Comment: Is there a reason against: `var sites = json_encode($sites);`? (as JSON is a *subet* of JS object literals). I don't use PHP, but I am curious if there is a rational for this extra step.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done. Javascript (at the moment) doesn't have raw sockets. As a result, you can't call off to non-http network services like mysql. You could however wrap it using some horrible ajax API (SQL from javascript, no matter how it's accomplished, is a horrible idea).

Comment: Browser-side javascript doesn't have database access, but server side javascript can access databases.  Your answer seems to make an absolute statement about what cannot be done with javascript, but it isn't true on all javascript platforms.  The question is vague/unclear though.

Comment: Very true, I was assuming browser-side javascript. Good call.